# HTML5 : drawing round corner rectangle as animation

Tags: html, html5-canvas, html5-animation

I'm able to draw a rectangle with rounded corner with following code. What I'm looking is I want to form this as an animation - starting from one point and draw the line which ends at the beginning point. (like drawing with pencil)  Any ideas?

```
ctx.beginPath(); 
  ctx.moveTo(x,y+radius);
  ctx.lineTo(x,y+height-radius); 

  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x,y+height,x+radius,y+height);  
  ctx.lineTo(x+width-radius,y+height);  
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x+width,y+height,x+width,y+height-radius);  
  ctx.lineTo(x+width,y+radius);  
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x+width,y,x+width-radius,y);  
  ctx.lineTo(x+radius,y);  
  ctx.quadraticCurveTo(x,y,x,y+radius);  
  ctx.stroke();
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Canvases are double-buffered. You'll need to defer each step of the animation using `setTimeout()` to give the canvas a chance to draw your changes. **Update:** See [`requestAnimationFrame`](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/) as an alternative to `setTimeout()`.

I've created one example for you that draws each of your rectangle's segments by calling the context method and pausing. I think I know the particular animation you're looking for and this isn't it, but hopefully it gives you a good start.

Code below and a demo is here: http://jsfiddle.net/q8GcR/

```
function animateRoundRect(ctx, x, y, width, height, radius, delay) {
    commands = [
        ['moveTo', x,y+radius],
        ['lineTo', x,y+height-radius], 
        ['quadraticCurveTo', x,y+height,x+radius,y+height],  
        ['lineTo', x+width-radius,y+height],  
        ['quadraticCurveTo', x+width,y+height,x+width,y+height-radius],  
        ['lineTo', x+width,y+radius],  
        ['quadraticCurveTo', x+width,y,x+width-radius,y],  
        ['lineTo', x+radius,y],  
        ['quadraticCurveTo', x,y,x,y+radius]
    ];  

    function draw() {
        var args = commands.shift();
        var method = args.shift();
        ctx[method].apply(ctx, args);
        ctx.stroke();
        if (commands.length) {
            setTimeout(draw, delay);
        }
    }

    ctx.beginPath();
    draw();
}

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.lineWidth = 3;
ctx.strokeStyle = '#f00';
animateRoundRect(ctx, 20, 20, 250, 100, 10, 500);
```

Answer (score 0):

some defects like - outline is crude, code might not be upto mark, the last clearing is making the canvas entirly white. Can somebody enhance this code ?. Pls run the code in firefox or chrome.

code : http://jsfiddle.net/XnzhQ/1/

Comment: Please take care to mark an reply as answered, which ever is correct for you. that is what SO is for. ;-)